# Get selected value in dropdownlist field in customlist from parent custom list SharePoint list 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have two custom list which is parent and child. The connection is working properly where you select the parent then it will display associate child.

Customer Table (Parent list)

```
Customer ID  CustName Detail
1            Jack      Test
2            Brian     Test2
```

Product Table (Child List)

```
Customer ID Product Name
1           Nike
1           Adidas
1           Puma
2           Asic
```

So what i am trying to do is, i am now selected parent table let say 
Customer ID 1 then display associate child table as expected. Then i click add new. The Customer ID field is populated in dropdownlist however it does not select customer Id = 1.

Is that anyway to make it populate the value based on customer id on parent child?

Please advise

Comment: can you just show your query

Comment: I do not have query what i have is parent child relationship by sending a row field from parent to child list.

Comment: can you please elaborate or just give a snapshot of what exactly you are trying to do?